# When the classes of two finitely generated modules are equal in the Grothendieck group

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, algebraic-k-theory

Let $R$ be a Commutative Noetherian ring. Let $G_0(R)$ denote the Grothendieck group of the abelian category of finitely generated $R$-modules i.e. it is the abelian group generated by the isomorphism classes of finitely generated $R$-modules subject to the relation : $[M]=[M_1]+[M_2]$ if there is a short exact sequence of $R$-modules $0\to M_1\to M\to M_2\to 0$.

It can be shown that $G_0(R)$ is generated by the classes $[R/P]$ as $P$ runs over all prime ideals of $R$. Now my question is the following:

If $M,N$ are finitely generated $R$-modules such that $[M]=[N]$ in $G_0(R)$, then is it true that there exists short exact sequences of finitely generated $R$-modules $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ and $0\to A\to B'\to C\to 0$ such that $M\oplus B\cong N\oplus B'$ ?

Comment: I proved this as a lemma in [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2374488/116766). I'm curious where the argument originated, though; maybe it was Steven Landsburg as Dan Grayson suggests.

Comment: @Takumi Murayama: your answer has been really helpful. Thanks

Comment: @uno Do you have a source that proves $G_0(R)$ is generated by $[R/P]$ for prime ideals $P$ of $R$?

Comment: @JLinsta: you can prove it on your own ... If $M$ is a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring $R$, then there is a sequence of submodules $0=M_0\subseteq M_1\subseteq \cdots \subseteq M_n=M$ such that for each $0\le j\le n-1$, there is a prime ideal $P_j$ with $M_{j+1}/M_j \cong R/P_j$ (see the Chapter on Associated primes and primary decomposition in Matsumura for a proof of this). Now using the relations used to define $G_0(R)$, you can see $[M] \in \langle [R/P_j]: 0\le j \le n-1\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar was once pointed out by Steven Landsburg, that works in any exact category: there are exact sequences $0 \to A \to B\to C \to 0$ and $0 \to A' \to B'\to C' \to 0$ such that $ M \oplus B \oplus C \oplus A' \cong N \oplus B' \oplus C' \oplus A$.  It's an easy exercise.